# Academic/technical term to describe China's "The Party"

Tags: china, terminology, political-system, political-science

I've read a few poli-sci books that had large sections about China, and slowly it began to strike me as very odd how unwieldy it is to describe the institutional setup in China using formal terms. It is almost always described rather casually as "The Party" as the principal and the "government/state agencies" as the agent. While this isn't wrong, it seems unnecessarily ominous: "The Party" the oft-used shorthand for CPC is convenient but also reads rather casual.

Not that China's situation is all that unique. I'd image one would be hard-pressed to find a word to encapsulate all the nuance within any given country. For example, Her Majesty's government: royal prerogative vs parliamentarism.

Still, I think it is within our remit as political scientists to use as exact language as we can when the task demands it instead of throwing in the old sobriquet "...with Chinese characteristics".

### Question

What existing political science framework most closely resembles China's "The Party"? Quality metric: the more cerebral and formal-sounding the better. Would also need it to be neutral in connotation: neither positive-sounding nor negative-sounding.

**For clarity:** Imagine a more formal word as our answer that replaces "Party" in the below graphic from The Economist:

[image]

Comment: China is not even the first [one-party state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-party_state) so I'm not sure why you think some other word (than "party") is more appropriate/academic.

Comment: @Fizz Right, just trying to avoid using "party" looking for higher-syllable words, as pretentious as that sounds.

Comment: @Fizz Also "one-party state" glosses over the principal agent relationship as shown in the chart. It's not really about a word to describe their political system per se, but rather the term to describe how to classify a prominent fixture within their political system.

Comment: Not sure about the downvotes, can someone explain? I have researched this area extensively, I honestly feel I have a legitimate question.

Comment: @ArashHowaida I think the downvotes are driven by the fact that the question is pedantic and serves no meaningful or useful purpose. Most readers do not think your question is meritorious even though it is within the ambit of Politics.SE.

Comment: @ohwilleke I concede my purposes may be somewhat vain, but I don't see it as taking away from the intellectual integrity of the question as a whole, so others can use it in more constructive ways (as China is a big topic these days). But that's just me, thanks for the explanation, I won't protest if that's how the consensus lands.

Comment: More syllables do not make a word better. If "the Party" is, in the Chinese context, clear enough, using a different word would only create confusion.

Comment: It is certainly not a *party* in the way it is understood in Europe or the US, but it is very much as it was understood in other communist or fascist states. I do agree though that term *party* here is mostly a legacy term, from the times when this party had to compete for power with other parties. A bit like *G-d* in the Old Testament/Tanakh - in the early chapters it is merely represented as the *most powerful among the deities*, but later is claimed to be *the only G-d* in existence (but sometimes even still referred to by a plural term.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely enough, even a Peking University scholar [would](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-981-99-1882-9_16) identify the CCP with the selectorate of the [broader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selectorate_theory) theory with the same name. According to the former piece:

> The CCP is the selectorate—a body of people who are entitled to select government officials.

(There's an earlier open-access [version](https://www.nsd.pku.edu.cn/attachments/b729ceafe8b345ccba4362f1eaa1bbfd.pdf) of that for those inclined to read it.)

As for the broader theory--Wikipedia:

> Regimes are classified on a spectrum of coalition size, as opposed to conventional, categorical labels (for example, the authors define conventional democracy as a large coalition regime and autocracy as a small coalition regime. [...]

However, within that theory, the seltorate is only the broader ruling coalition, the narrower circle thereof that has actual/more power is dubbed the "winning coalition".

> [image]
>
> In The Dictator's Handbook, Bueno de Mesquita and Smith state five rules that leaders should use to stay in power:
>
> - The smaller the winning coalition, the fewer people to satisfy to remain in control.
> - Having a large nominal selectorate gives a pool of potential people to replace dissenters in coalition.
> - Maintain control of revenue flows to redistribute to your friends.
> - But only pay friends enough that they will not consider overthrowing you and at the same time little enough so that they depend on you.
> - Don't take your friends' money and redistribute it to the masses.

I'm not going to try here to ascertain precisely whom is in the [narrower] "winning coalition" within the CCP, but surely from your diagram the Politburo and friends qualify.

The Peking paper avoids identifying the winning coalition in China. It is also quite effusive of the CCP otherwise, and even claims [somewhat contradictorily] that "in China the selectorate does not consist of people, but of rules that govern the selection process". Probably most Western political scientists would disagree on that. In a similar [paper](http://repec.dems.unimib.it/repec/pdf/mibwpaper230.pdf) co-authored with a Westerner, the same Peking author also declares that
"In our paper, [...] there is no distinction between the winning coalition and the selectorate. In fact they coincide, and allows us to focus on the notion of reciprocal accountability [...]" So, yeah, I could half-joke here and say that [some] Chinese scholars only accept a "selectorate theory with Chinese characteristics" at least as pertaining to China.

OTOH a general [criticism](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/10.1146/annurev-polisci-071213-041224) of the selectorate  theory (not just of this Peking version thereof) is that

> measurement of the sizes of the selectorate and winning coalition is flawed

And even if you don't buy the absoluteness of the flaw, it's clear that there are differences/difficulties in agreeing on them for many particular examples. As mentioned in the latter piece, other authors only identify the Central Committee of the CCP as the selectorate in China. And the problem of identification is not merely confined to China, but more broadly to other one-party states, e.g.

> The make-up of a selectorate and how it morphs over time in size, composition, and preferences are crucial empirical issues; as Stern asks (1978, p. 343), “If the core of the ‘selectorate’ lies in the Party, how far up the Communist ladder does one have to go to find it?” Moreover, the problem in determining the identity of the selectorate is not merely academic, as uncertainty is a core characteristic of autocratic systems. For example, “[w]ith the levers of political, military, and economic power in diverse and often highly ambitious hands after Stalin's death, there was for a time considerable confusion as to the ultimate source of political patronage” (Stern 1978, p. 343).
>
> [...] the composition of the selectorate was a critical factor for those seeking policy reforms in the USSR and China. The policy preferences of the members of the selectorate mattered, and rulers sought to shift the composition of the selectorate's membership in order to effect policy change. [However...] the selectorate is not well defined even in these highly institutionalized authoritarian systems.

TLDR: [by now] you can hopefully see why it's difficult to apply other frameworks to one-party states.

---

Less controversially, the CCP [has](https://publishing.cdlib.org/ucpressebooks/view?docId=ft0k40035t&chunk.id=d0e2140&toc.id=&brand=ucpress) a [principal-agent relationship](https://www.thebalancemoney.com/what-is-a-principal-agent-relationship-in-business-4775356) with their government.

> The language of Western institutional economics is useful for conceptualizing the formal authority relationship between Communist Party and government: It is an "agency relationship" in which the Communist Party is the "principal" and the government is the "agent." The Party has formal political authority over the government, which does the actual work of administering the country. The Party's authority over the government is based primarily on its authority to appoint and promote government officials [...] The Party also sets the general policy line (lù xiàn), which the government implements, and oversees the work of the government. Finally, it is responsible for the ideological remolding of government cadres and of all other members of society.

But

> The crucial difference between communist and democratic systems is the political accountability of the principals. In communist systems the Communist Party is not formally accountable to the citizenry; it claims to reflect the will of the people by leading them toward a communist future, but there is no institutional mechanism making them accountable to citizens' present preferences.

Comment: Great find! This is helpful, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suppose if we want to be technical about it we should call it a authoritarian corporate bureaucracy. That was literally the intention in its formation: for the state to take over the role of private corporations in managing the nation's industries, ostensible in the name of the laboring classes. I'm not sure how much impact the last phrase currently has (or ever had, for that matter), but the modern Party functions almost exactly like the bureaucracy of a large corporation. All decisions, including decisions about advancement and promotion, are matters of secretive internal power politics.

The system is not nepotistic enough to be considered a dynasty, and not sufficiently centralized to be an autocracy, so...